# HostBinding not working as expected when applying class

Tags: angular

I was reading an article about common bad practices when creating components.  One of the things the article mentioned was adding extra tags (like ) to your component template to group everything generated by the component.  This is unnecessary because everything generated by your component is already grouped in its selector tags.  Makes sense, so I wanted to go about cleaning this up in my code.

So I wanted to use @HostBinding to apply the style class to the component and remove the unneeded  tag, but it's not working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here's a basic example.  The classes that I'm trying to apply are from bootstrap css.

Before:

```
import {Component, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

and the template

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h1>Welcome to {{title}}!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
    <ul>
      <li><h2>x</h2></li>
      <li><h2>y</h2></li>
      <li><h2>z</h2></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works like I want to.  The container is centered in the middle of the screen.

I removed the outermost div from the template and then added @HostBinding to the component.

After:

```
import {Component, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') className = 'container';
  title = 'app';
}
```

And the updated template

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <h1>Welcome to {{title}}!</h1>
</div>

<div class="col-md-5">
  <h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
  <ul>
    <li><h2>x</h2></li>
    <li><h2>y</h2></li>
    <li><h2>z</h2></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I use my browser's dev tools to inspect the generated page, the class is there (my app-root tag has the class="container" attribute on it), but the style is incorrect.  Am I missing or misunderstanding something when it comes to HostBinding?

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the rendered template here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions about your app, but I think the issue is that you're probably trying to use it in your **root component**, meaning that it will be trying to set that class on a parent element that Angular doesnt have any control over.

If you had a child component within your `app-root` then you could use `@HostBinding('class') className = 'container';` in the child component to set a class for the parent (`app-root`) component.

Comment: That's a correct assumption.  I had made the very simple test project to play around with HostBinding and was trying to use it with the root component.  I switched the root back to using the div in the template and then created a component that I added to the root.  That child component used Host Binding and everything was working as expected with that child component.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: This sample illustrates the problem. The `app-root` is created in your html file, so angular didn't technically create it but I'm not quite sure why it isn't clever enough to bind to it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbfr8n

Comment: Note that it does apply `_nghost-c0` and `ng-version`